# What is expected in setting up the following dutch auction?

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets, auctions

This is quite possibly not a question within the scope of stackexchange but please help out.

I am trying to do an solidity project in which a dutch auction is to be implemented and the auction logic is as follows:

> ```
> The auction is initiated with a start date, end date and a start price.
>
> The price is always known at any time as the linear line connecting the points:
> ```
>
> a) start date, start price. (startPrice = a · startDate + b)
>
> b) end date, 0. (0 = a · end date + b)

I don't understand the logic behind setting up the start date and end date. What exactly is the formula they are expecting to be used here?
I would highly appreciate it if someone could explain what 'linear line' means here as well.

Comment: It looks like an error. I would interpret it as "..as the line connecting...". Without more point it is just a line.

Comment: @Ismael 
Yes it does seem to be an error. Do you think you could expand on what a and b means here or about the logic on how to implement it?

Comment: `a` and `b` are numeric values. The price at time `x` will be `a . x + b`. In order to determine the values the equations: `0 = a . end_date b` and `start_price = a . start_date + b` must be resolved.

Comment: @Ismael, so what are the values that we supply here? Should we give all the values a, b and startprice?

Comment: The values for `start_price`, `start_date` and `end_date` should be defined when the contract will launch. Then you have a system of two linear equations with two unknowns `a` and `b`, solving the system you'll obtain the values for `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Ismael could you suggest any way to solve linear equations within a smart contract? Are there any available packages or methods you'd suggest?

Comment: The equations apply in the general case. For a contract I'd implement them without the parameters `a` and `b` just create the linear function.

Answer (score 0):

At deploy time configure the parameters `startDate`, `endDate` and `startingPrice`.

Then at time `date` the current price will be returned by `getCurrentPrice(date)`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC

pragma solidity 0.8.14;


contract A {
    uint256 public startDate;
    uint256 public endDate;
    uint256 public startingPrice;


    constructor(uint256 _startDate, uint256 _endDate, uint256 _startingPrice) {
        require(_startDate < _endDate, "Invalid date range");
        startDate = _startDate;
        endDate = _endDate;
        startingPrice = _startingPrice;
    }

    function getCurrentPrice(uint256 date) public view returns (uint256) {
        require((date >= startDate) && (date < endDate), "Invalid date");
        return (endDate - date) * startingPrice / (endDate - startDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey is 'date' available inbuilt in solidity? Or is it to be declared separately?

Comment: @Mehsilsem If you want to get the "current" date (and time) use `block.timestamp`.

Comment: I tried changing it as required but it doesn't seem to be working. Can you please take a look at it here : https://gist.github.com/anandasaia/6bea1bb45dca1ffdcef91bdd2b8b432b

Comment: @Mehsilsem Please ask in a separate question.

Comment: Done, please answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/129909/100242